# XSL- simple example fails

Tags: xslt

I have a simple xslt script:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/package">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which when applied to the following example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<package
    xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
    version="3.0" 
    xml:lang="en" 
    unique-identifier="pub-identifier"
>
    <metadata>
        <dc:identifier id="pub-identifier">_idm462750791920</dc:identifier>
        <meta id="meta-identifier" property="dcterms:identifier">_idm462750791920</meta>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

produces a non-sensical result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


_idm462750791920
_idm462750791920
```

Note that I don't use the elements related to the dc namespace, things works as one would expect.  For example, if I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<package
    xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
    version="3.0" 
    xml:lang="en" 
    unique-identifier="pub-identifier"
>
<metadata>
    asdfasdfads
</metadata>
</package>
```

So it DOES seem that it's recognizing the "package" element and acting on it as I expect.

What do I have to do make this work?

Comment: `/package` doesn't match anything because package is in a default namespace. Do a quick search on xslt default namespace and you'll find tons of examples. Also the nonsensical result is because of xslt's built-in templates. I'll add a link to the specs when I get back to a computer.

Comment: What *is* the expected result here?

Comment: @michail - I expect to get display all the text within the package element.

Comment: @RobertRamey Please edit your question and post the **exact** result (as code) you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that I don't use the elements related to the dc namespace, things works as one would expect.

What are you expecting? This would result in the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

        asdfasdfads
```

Which is not what I would expect from `<xsl:copy-of select="*"/>` if `/package` was selected properly.

> So it DOES seem that it's recognizing the "package" element and acting on it as I expect.

Nope, sorry it doesn't. What you are seeing is the result of [XSLT's built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule).

The `/package` element is in the default namespace `http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf`. What you can do is bind that namespace uri to a prefix and use that in your XPath's (in the `match`).

Note: The prefix that you use doesn't matter, just as long as the uri is the same.

Example...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
  <xsl:template match="/opf:package">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output of your first input example:**

```
<metadata xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
    <dc:identifier id="pub-identifier">_idm462750791920</dc:identifier>
    <meta id="meta-identifier" property="dcterms:identifier">_idm462750791920</meta>
</metadata>
```

**Output of your second input example:**

```
<metadata xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">
    asdfasdfads
</metadata>
```

If any of this is different than what you are expecting for output, please update your question with the exact output you're expecting/wanting.